# Need Help regarding .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using ErrorDocument 404 /404.php for the custom 404 page. this will display while someone type pages not there. But While someone types https://mywebsite.in/?df or https://mywebsite.in/abc.php/?ab same page appears and is indexed in google as well. what I will do?

Comment: Please confirm through your browsers inspector tools that the HTTP status code is in fact 404

Comment: Checked Status is : 200

Comment: In your htaccess, do you have a central router to a file such as index.php?

Comment: `abc.php` and `index.php` exist. Check the provided parameters and throw header(s) as expected.

Comment: @ChrisHaas No i do not have central router to a file in htaccess

Comment: The second one, `/abc.php/?ab`, you can prevent from "working" via the [`AcceptPathInfo`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) directive. The first one you will have to handle explicitly - the server does not know, which parameter names (and which values, if you want to check those as well) are valid. So you would either have to check that via mod_rewrite, or handle it directly from within your PHP scripts.

Comment: Are you using query strings or path-info (2nd example) on any of your legitimate URLs?